# What's the best small dataset to train a Recurrent Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning

I work on a neural network library in C++ and I'm in the process of implementing recurrent neural networks.
I run my tests on a GitHub server on different datasets, Iris and Wine for simple unit tests, MNIST and Fashion MNIST for test the MLP, CIFAR-10 for test the CNN and I looking for some new dataset to train the RNN that I implement.

**Do you have any idea of small datasets to train my RNN?**

I'm looking for one or two small datasets that are easy to integrate into my tests in my continuous delivery process. About 30 seconds for 1 epoch with more than 70-80% accuracy would be ideal.

*PS: I know I can use MNIST to simulate temporal data but having a "real" dataset would be better and more diversified.*